# Pip install -e rewrites easy-install.pth

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have two packages and a virtualenv. And, I'm trying to install them both into this virtualenv in editable mode, this means "*python setup.py develop*" or "*pip install -e*". This procedure usually leads to three things:

1. Real path to package is added as file **venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/package.egg-link**
2. The same path is also added into **venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth**
3. **package.egg-info** with metadata stuff is create in package working dir

So, I have a problem with step 2. Depending of the installation order, if I install package A first and package B second (using the same *pip install -e*) everything works and both paths are in **easy-install.pth**. But otherwise, if I install package B first and package A second - the second one overwrites **easy-install.pth** and there is only one path there - B.

Packages A and B have no any dependencies on each other. What's pip's problem?

Comment: Can you specify which two packages you're trying to install?

Comment: These are just two packages our team is working on - REST service and sample plugin for it to interact through stevedore (https://review.openstack.org/#/c/104608/). Actually, this looks as a bug in Pip, because when I replaced "pip install -e" with "python setup.py develop" everything did work as expected.

Comment: not working in either case :(